# Best Transactional Support API for HBASE

Tags: transactions, hbase, apache-omid

What's the best transaction support API for Hbase ?
I found `OMID` and `Haeinsa` .
First I tried with omid but when I reboot my system it's Timestamp restarts too. 
Now I decided to trying `Haeinsa` .Any body can help me between them ?
Can I fix this problem of `OMID` ??

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now HBase has a proposal for generic transaction API in [HBASE-11447](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-11447). I think OMID, Haeinsa and Phoenix are gonna support it.

We have implemented the transaction and report to community in [HBASE-10999](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-10999). It's totally open-source and you can check out in https://github.com/XiaoMi/themis .

Comment: HI tobe  !
I'm testing your api themis . but when I put some row then delete them
and then scan table I see all of the row in scan result but no in get result only scan . why ?What's the way ?

Comment: I have reported this issue to my colleagues. They will leave you messages soon.

Comment: any news ?What shall I do ?

Comment: Themis has been well tested and we don't find this issue before. We will contact you ASAP, maybe tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you ! I have to using Themis for my project .

Comment: @Mark You can email to us and give me your code of using themis. Here's the address cuijianwei@xiaomi.com. Any question is welcome.

Comment: Thank you a lot . I will be mail soon.

Comment: Hi@Mark We haven't received your email. Please email to cuijianwei@xiaomi.com and cc to chendihao@xiaomi.com. We will contact you if you leave your email.

Comment: Hi @tobe I mailed only to cuijianwei@xiaomi.com and he answered me.But now he don't answer my last mail ,Is it any problem for him ?tnx

Comment: Hi, @Mark. He's reading your email now. We will try our best to help you out about themis. You can cc the email to me, chendihao@xiaomi.com.